# Using Thread in GUI application

Tags: c++, qt

I am making a multiple game. I need to take command from client. This means I have GUI and TcpServer. So I need to work them simultaneously. I used Thread but it doesnt work. Could you please help me to find the problem? 
Summarizing: Firstly player press the "online" button. Then Oyun() Gui function runs and button connected with connectPressed() function. In this function there is a thread in order to run read the client commands when Gui is working.

Firstly I used QTimer in order to take command from Client in every 1 second. But My GUI freezed. And Then I used QThread but according to my research, QThread is not proper for GUI app. So I found Qtconcurrent, QFutureWatcher and QFuture. But my thread is still not working. I should have made a mistake somewhere.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <anaclass.h>
#include <player2.h>
#include <tcpserver.h>
#include <QThread>
#include <QObject>
//#include <worker.h>

AnaClass *anaclass;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    anaclass = new AnaClass();
    anaclass->show();
    anaclass->Giris();   //button selection page

    return a.exec();
}
```

```
#include "anaclass.h"

Puan *puanlama1;
Puan *puanlama2;
player2 *yilan2;


AnaClass::AnaClass() : QGraphicsView()
{
    setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
    setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOn);
    setFixedSize(800,600);

    scene = new QGraphicsScene;
    scene->setSceneRect(0,0,800,600);
    setScene(scene);
}

void AnaClass::Giris()
{
    connectButton = new Button("Online");
    double cxPos = this->width()/2 - connectButton->boundingRect().width()/2;
    double cyPos= 425;
    connectButton->setPos(cxPos, cyPos);
    connect(connectButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(connectPressed()));
    scene->addItem(connectButton);
}

void AnaClass::Oyun()
{
    scene->clear();

    puanlama1 = new Puan();
    puanlama1->setDefaultTextColor(Qt::blue);
    puanlama1->setPos(5, 2);
    scene->addItem(puanlama1);

    yilan = new Yilan();
    yilan->setRect(0,0,19,19);
    scene->addItem(yilan);

    yilan->setFlags(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsFocusable);
    yilan->setFocus();

    QBrush brush;
    brush.setStyle(Qt::SolidPattern);
    brush.setColor(Qt::blue);
    yilan->setBrush(brush);
    if(stringButtonName == "Player2" || stringButtonName == "Online")
    {
    yilan->setPos(scene->width()/2 + 60, scene->height()/2);
    }
    else
    {
     yilan->setPos(scene->width()/2, scene->height()/2);
    }

    if(stringButtonName == "Player2" || stringButtonName == "Online")
    {
    yilan->playerNumber=1;

    puanlama2 = new Puan();
    puanlama2->setDefaultTextColor(Qt::green);
    puanlama2->setPos(700, 2);
    scene->addItem(puanlama2);

    yilan2 = new player2();
    yilan2->setRect(0,0,19,19);
    scene->addItem(yilan2);

    yilan2->setFlags(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsFocusable);
    yilan2->setFocus();

    QBrush brush2;
    brush2.setStyle(Qt::SolidPattern);
    brush2.setColor(Qt::green);
    yilan2->setBrush(brush2);
    yilan2->setPos(scene->width()/2 - 60,scene->height()/2);

    }

    emit emitTcp();
}

void AnaClass::connectPressed()
{
    qDebug()<<"connect basildi";
    server = new TCPServer();
    server->Test();
    stringButtonName = connectButton->buttonName;

    qDebug()<<"Gelen Veri " + server->OkunanBilgi;
    QFutureWatcher<void> watcher;
    connect(&watcher, SIGNAL(finished()), server, SLOT(daimaOku()), Qt::QueuedConnection);
    QFuture<void> deneme = QtConcurrent::run(this, &AnaClass::emitTcp);
    watcher.setFuture(deneme);
    Oyun();
}
}
```

```
#ifndef ANACLASS_H
#define ANACLASS_H

#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <yilan.h>
#include <Meyve.h>
#include <QBrush>
#include <Puan.h>
#include <player2.h>
#include <QThread>
#include <label.h>
#include <QKeyEvent>
#include <button.h>
#include <QDebug>
#include <tcpserver.h>
#include <QTime>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QMutex>
//#include <worker.h>
#include <QFuture>
#include <QtConcurrent>
#include <QFutureWatcher>

class AnaClass : public QGraphicsView
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    AnaClass();
    void Giris();
    void Oyun();
    void timerEvent(QTimerEvent *event);
    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event2);

public:
    Yilan *yilan;
    //QThread *thread;
    QGraphicsScene *scene;
    Label *label1;
    Button* player1Button;
    Button* player2Button;
    Button* connectButton;
    TCPServer *server;
    QTimer *timerOnline;


public:
    int k=0;
    int t=0;
    QString stringButtonName;

signals:
    void emitTcp();

public slots:
    void connectPressed();
    void player1Pressed();
    void player2Pressed();
};
#endif // ANACLASS_H
```

```
#define TCPSERVER_H

#include <QTcpServer>
#include <QTcpSocket>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QObject>
#include <QTimer>

class TCPServer : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    TCPServer(QObject* parent = nullptr);
    void Test();

signals:
    //void emitTcp();

public slots:
    void newConnection();
    void daimaOku();  // always read as english

public:
    QTcpServer *server;
    QTcpSocket *socket;
    QTimer *timerTcp;
    QString OkunanBilgi;

};
#endif // TCPSERVER_H
```

```
#include "tcpserver.h"

TCPServer::TCPServer(QObject * parent) : QObject()
{

}

void TCPServer::Test()
{
    server = new QTcpServer();

    connect(server, SIGNAL(newConnection()), this, SLOT(newConnection()));

    if(!server->listen(QHostAddress::Any, 1234))
    {
        qDebug()<<"server baslamadi";
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug()<<"server basladi";
    }

    //timerTcp = new QTimer();
    //connect(timerTcp, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(daimaOku()));
    //emit emitTcp();
}

void TCPServer::newConnection()
{
    qDebug()<<"newconnection";
 socket = server->nextPendingConnection();
 socket->write("Merhaba Client");
 socket->flush();

 socket->waitForBytesWritten(5000);

 timerTcp->start(50);
}

void TCPServer::daimaOku()  //alwaysread() as english
{
      qDebug()<<"always read function is working";

//    if(socket->state() == QAbstractSocket::ConnectedState)
//    {
//    qDebug()<<"Daima oku fonsiyonu soket bagli";
//    socket->waitForReadyRead();
//    OkunanBilgi = socket->readAll();
//    qDebug()<<"Tcp daima oku :" + OkunanBilgi;
//    }
}
```

Comment: You should eliminate statements like `socket->waitForBytesWritten(5000);` from the code then you don't need a thread. Instead you can connect signals and put `timerTcp->start(50);` in a slot. See this signal: [https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#bytesWritten](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#bytesWritten)

Comment: With Qt, all operations of GUI classes have to happen on the *main* thread. You cannot do GUI stuff on other threads - go through the event loop for any GUI stuff.

Comment: You don't need threading at all. Take a look at Qt's [Fortune Client Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-fortuneclient-example.html) and [Fortune Server Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-fortuneserver-example.html) for an inspiration on how to use signals/slots in such a case.

Comment: in the begining I made Tcpserver and Tcpclient program with signal/slot. It worked smoothly. Then I made game and I combined Tcp and game. Firstly I used signal/slot but it didnt work. Then I used QThread with/without worker class, It didnt work. Because thread should'nt be used in Gui app. I tried Qtimer but I failed again. Now I will try your advices. As I understood from your comments, I will remove waitForBytesWritten and I used signal/slots again. But where? Should I use it in anaclass.cpp or in tcpserver.cpp or in main.cpp (I think i cant use it on main.cpp)?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your comments. I solved the problem by deleting QFuture and adding connect() like below.

```
timerOnline = new QTimer();
connect(timerOnline, SIGNAL(timeout()), server, SLOT(daimaOku()));
timerOnline->start(500);
```

But I have another problem. When Client connects the server, my Gui app freezes. You can find the revised code below.

```
void TCPServer::daimaOku()
{
  qDebug()<<"Function is running";
  if(socket->state() == QAbstractSocket::UnconnectedState)
  {
  qDebug()<<"Socket is not connected";
  }
  else
  {
      qDebug()<<"Socket connected";
      socket->waitForReadyRead();
      OkunanBilgi = socket->readAll();
      qDebug()<<"Tcp always read :" + OkunanBilgi;
  }
```

}

When client is not connected, the output is:

Function is running

Socket is not connected

Socket is not connected ...

I can play the game but when client is connected, game freezes. I don't understand why.

Comment: I deleted socket->waitForReadyRead(); and my problem is solved. This means GUI hates waitForReadyRead() and waitForBytesWritten() functions. Because they are blocking GUI thread.